# Beamer content (text) offset/shifts to top when large image is used

Tags: beamer

I have a small problem. When I insert a large image inside a frame, which in my opinion still fits, the content moves to the top. While I have set that all content must be aligned to the top, but due to the image it moves even further to the top. I really want that the content just stays were it is.

This example illustrates the situation. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{boxes}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{General formalization of haplotyping.}
  \begin{definition}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
    \item
    \item 
    \item
    \item
    \end{itemize}
  \end{definition}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill[blue!40!white] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]{General formalization of haplotyping.}
  \begin{definition}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
    \item
    \item 
    \item
    \item
    \end{itemize}
  \end{definition}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill[blue!40!white] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `beamer` vertically centres the slide's contents. Is the previous contents of the slides (the definition) the same on both slides? That is, is it the 'jump' you are concerned about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the definition/items are the same on the two slides and you are concerned about the 'jump' when you go from the first to second slide, the solution is to use a single frame and either the `overprint` or `overlayarea` environment. In this case, the simpler but less flexible `overprint` will do the job:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{boxes}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]{General formalization of haplotyping.}
    \begin{definition}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item
        \item
        \item
        \item
        \item
      \end{itemize}
    \end{definition}
    \begin{overprint}
      \onslide<1>
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \fill[blue!40!white] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}
      \onslide<2>\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \fill[blue!40!white] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}
    \end{overprint}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Use of <code>overprint</code> to stabilise text in <code>beamer</code>]